# Minus/Sum a table with itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this :

```
id product_property_id product_id amount type
1       1                  145      10    0
2       4                  145      12    0
3       6                  145      13    1
4       23                 147      2     0
5       4                  145      15    1 
6       4                  145      2     1
```

`type` :

0: out

1: in

what I want :

for example :

`product_id` **145** with `product_property_id` **4** :

(15+2) - 12 = 5

```
product_id   product_property_id  new_amout
  145              4                  5
```

is it possible to use `SQL` to get this result or I have to use `php` instant of it ?

Comment: always `in ` is more than `out ` in my table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just a query using conditional aggregation:

```
select product_id, product_property_id,
       sum(case when type = 1 then amount
                when type = 0 then - amount
                else 0
           end) as new_amount
from likethis
group by product_id, product_property_id;
```

Comment: Using arithmetic expressions is always more fun than conditional logic: `sum((2*type-1)*amount)` ;)

Comment: @symcbean, maybe true, but hopeless code to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT  product_id,
        product_property_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN amount END) - SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN amount END) new_amount
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE product_id = 145
AND product_property_id = 4
GROUP BY product_id,
         product_property_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  product_id,
        product_property_id,
        SUM((2*[type]-1) * amount) as sum 
FROM    Table
WHERE   product_id = 145
AND     product_property_id = 4
GROUP BY product_id,
         product_property_id;
```

Comment: I like this idea, but you are using an `x` instead of `*` to multiply

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 SELECT product_id, product_property_id,
 SUM(IF(type=1,amount,0))-SUM(IF(type=0,amount,0)) as my_value 
 FROM `my_table` GROUP BY product_property_id
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/728c2/1)**